# A replacement for HoneyProxy (dumping requests into a directory like structure)?

Tags: directory, dump, http-proxy, mitmproxy, burp

I'm looking for a HTTP/HTTPS proxy with the capability of dumping the requests into a directory like structure. For example if I request example.com/path/example.html, example.html will be stored in a  somedir/example.com/path/example.html in my local disk. I know that Honeyproxy provides this feature, but it has a bug that currently doesn't work with my code. Other HTTP/HTTPS proxies like mite, burp, node-mitm-proxy,... only dump the traffic itself and don't give us a directory structure of the requests. 
So would you please suggest me any other proxy that has this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use mitmproxy with https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/integrate_honeyproxy/scripts/core/dirdumper.py

Comment: Thanks  for the suggestion. The problem is that the bug I get from Honey Proxy is originated from mite proxy [link] (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/383). I'm using a headless browser to open a page. I create a new process for each request and then I kill it. So all the assocoaited sockets would be closed. It works fine by itself but when I use honey proxy, mitm proxy dose not close it's sockets to the web server. So after a while, mitm would have lots of sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state and then it stops. I'm using the latest version of honey proxy(1.1)!!

Comment: You can use the aforementioned script with the latest version of mitmproxy, which is not affected by #383.